# Timeout function for FormsAuthenticationTicket stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I seriously need help. I spent to much time trying to figure out what happened.
I use a FormsAuthenticationTicket to manage the users connection. As here:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1, userName, System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout),
        false, "", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
        encryptedTicket);
authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

So nothing crazy. I did some updates on my live website (but not on the ticket code) and now when I get timed out, the "ReturnUrl" parameter is not in the Url of the login page anymore.

My question is: Do you have any basic recommendation of where to search when a ticket starts to act up?

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you do any update in the config file ?

Comment: No, no update in the config file

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution so I put it for the other people that might have a problem.

Another file Web.config was missing on the production server. The only thing that this file has in it is:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <authorization> 
       <deny users="?" /> 
    </authorization> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Now the timeout function works again. If someone has any explanation of why this code is helpful, I'd like to know it.